# use ? in first of url

Tags: .htaccess

I want use below link and load from `category.php` but it does not work

```
http://test.com/?search=x
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^search$ category.php?search=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Do you want to pass query string i.e. `?search=x` to `category.php`?

Comment: @anubhava yes, i want load from category

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://category.php?search=%1 [R=302,L]
```

The reason you can't get away with a single `RewriteRule` is that query parameters cannot be directly rewritten.  Instead, the above code captures the query string using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`, which is then made available as `%1` in the `RewriteRule` which follows.  The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` ensures that the code will only evaluate for the `test.com` domain.

Comment: I don't want redirect

Comment: Did you actually try my answer?

Comment: Your code redirect to new url, but i want load category.php

Comment: Doesn't your requirement necessitate a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?search=%1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ category.php [L]
```

- Pattern `^/?$` ensures that we match only landing page, nothing else.
- `QUERY_STRING` is automatically appended to target URI so there is no need to capture and append in target URI.